# Modify directory structure from array

Tags: bash, macos, shell

Say I have an existing file structure like:

```
com/example/test/file1.txt
com/example/test/file2.sh
```

And a directories array of strings like `directories=(net john doe foo)`

I would like to modify the folder structure above using `bash` so the end result is:

```
net/john/doe/foo/file1.txt
net/john/doe/foo/file2.sh
```

the amount of directories is always 2 or more. The file types can be anything. I tried using `mv` but ended up typing a lot of dumb code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
newdir=$(IFS=/; echo "${directories[*]}")
mkdir -p "$newdir"
mv com/example/test/* "$newdir"
```

#### Alternatives

Another method for creating `newdir` is:

```
newdir=$(printf '%s/' "${directories[@]}")
```

Also, if `com/example/test/*` in the `mv` command above is too broad, then:

```
mv com/example/test/{file1.txt,file2.sh} "$newdir"
```

Comment: Nice, and then just `rm -r` the old `com` directory, right?

Comment: @David Yes.  If you're done with it, you can run `rm -f com`.